# why can't i enter if condition 3 and 4. 1 and 2 are working fine for this sample banking code

Tags: python

please can anyone check my code and correct me why I am unable to enter if statement when I was given option input==3 and option input==4.

```
import sys,os,math
Account_balance= int(25000)
print('*** WELCOME TO SBI BANK NAKKALAGUTTA ***')
givenpin=input('Enter The 4 Digit  Pin Number ')
if givenpin =='0351':enter code here
    print('welcome MR.Anudeep RAO')
else:
    print('unauthorized access try again')
sys.exit()
print('your A/C number is: 10987xxxxxx')
print("### choose  an option  below ###")
print("""
1)        Balance
2)        Withdraw
3)        Deposit
4)        Quit
""")
option = int(input("Enter option:"))
if option == 1:
     print('your Account balance is' +' '+ str(int(Account_balance)) +'Rs/-')
elif option == 2:
      input_to_Withdraw = int(input("enter amount to withdraw "))

      if input_to_Withdraw > 25000:
          print("Insufficient Funds in Your A/C")
      elif input_to_Withdraw < 25000:
          present_balance = (Account_balance - input_to_Withdraw)
          print('collect cash and available balance is ' + str(int(present_balance)))

          if option == 3:
              Input_to_Deposit = int(input("enter amount to deposit into A/C "))
              print('deposited balance is:')
              print(Account_balance +Input_to_Deposit)

              if option == 4:
                  print('Transaction complete leave  bank safely  Bye:')
```

Comment: Your `if option == 3` statement is _inside_ the block that only happens if `option == 2`.

Comment: Check your indentation levels - your `if option == 3:` and `if option == 4:` statements should be at the same indentation level as `elif option == 2:`, not inside it -- and ideally they should also use `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

The `if option == 3:` and `if option == 4:` cases are deep inside the `elif option == 2:` case. Since you don't reset the value of `option` anywhere, I assume this is a mistake.

Fix the indentation of these two cases so your code has a chance to follow these paths. They should be at the same indentation level as `elif option == 2:`.

Comment: yup got it bro thanks a lot. its about indentation .but why it  is so

Comment: Hi @ErrabellyAnudeepRao. Since Python doesn't use braces to start and end code blocks (like if statements and loops) it uses indentation level to tell where a block ends.